# What is an authoritative source for neologisms in Ukrainian?

Tags: терміни, запозичені-слова, неологізми, language-regulation

Is there an authoritative source for new words and terms like, for example, an application (a computer program)? I am aware of http://slovotvir.org.ua, however words presented there quite often sound questionable (subjective), besides that many of them are still under discussion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems that the [NASU Institute of Ukrainian Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASU_Institute_of_Ukrainian_Language) (see its [official website](http://www1.nas.gov.ua/institutes/ium/about/Pages/default.aspx) (in Ukrainian)) would be the entity officially entitled to take care of incorporating new words and terms into the language.

They have [published a dictionary](https://books.google.com.ua/books/about/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD.html?hl=uk&id=ww0qAQAAIAAJ) of neologisms a few years ago.

Comment: _A dictionary of neologisms, published a few years ago_ sounds a bit sad, don't you think?

Comment: @ata_zh, in the world of Internet and electronic communications publishing on papers is doomed to look slow and outdated, but that's what paper publishing is. Consider it a milestone mark :-)

Comment: what keeps NASU from making electronic dictionaries?

Comment: @ata_zh I have no idea. You can try contacting them and persuading to consider this option :-) since we don't write books by hand anymore, there should be some electronic sources they could put online, I suppose.